# An simple mdx error, unknown-member measures.unit_name used in query

Tags: mdx, cube, hyperion

We are using hyperion, but this simeple mdx caused the error:"unknown-member measures.unit_name used in query".
why? Is "Measures" available in hyperion? Or do we need enable it?
Please help.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Unit_Name] AS '[Organization].currentmember.member_name'

SELECT {
    [Measures].[Unit_Name]
} on columns,
{
    [organization].[40-00012].members
} on rows from OPEXDSH3.OPEXDSH3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to retrieve the Organizatios catalog, 
Did you try using DIMENSION PROPERTIES syntax?

```
Select 
   {[Measures].DefaultMember} On Columns,
   {[organization].[40-00012].members} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_KEY On Rows 
From OPEXDSH3.OPEXDSH3
```